# MySQL connection not available at first query after a few hours of downtime

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, orm, mysql-connector

After a few hours of downtime, when querying the database (I use Sqlalchemy ORM), the exception "MySQL connection not available" is triggered, but when querying again, everything works properly.

[Here's a traceback.](https://gist.github.com/inlovewithxanny/1b2ab5f8894ad1d3f95a9c7ce1fa9dbf)

I use context manager to establish connection, make a query and then close connection. Here's an example:

```py
def get_all_makers_sorted() -> list[Maker] | None:
    with SessionLocal() as session:
        makers = session.query(Maker).order_by(Maker.level.desc()).all()
    return makers
```

And this is how my SQLAlchemy is setted up:

```
database/
|____ database.py
|____ methods.py
|____ orm_models.py
```

**database.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, DeclarativeBase
from config import MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE, MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_PORT

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{MYSQL_USER}:{MYSQL_PASSWORD}@{MYSQL_HOST}:{MYSQL_PORT}/{MYSQL_DATABASE}"
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base: DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()
```

For **methods.py** you alredy have seen the example above.

**orm_models.py**

```
from typing import Literal
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger, Column, Date, ForeignKey, TIMESTAMP, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

from .database import Base


class Publication(Base):
    __tablename__ = "publications"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    publication_number: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=True)
    maker_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("makers.id"), nullable=True)
    date = Column(Date(), nullable=True)
    information_creator_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("makers.id"), nullable=True
    )
    status: Mapped[Literal["in_process", "completed", "failed"]] = mapped_column(
        server_default="in_process"
    )
    amount_dp: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
    salary_payer_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("makers.id"), nullable=True)

    maker_rel = relationship(
        "Maker",
        back_populates="publications_made",
        foreign_keys=[maker_id],
        primaryjoin="Publication.maker_id == Maker.id",
    )

    information_creator_rel = relationship(
        "Maker",
        back_populates="publications_created",
        foreign_keys=[information_creator_id],
        primaryjoin="Publication.information_creator_id == Maker.id",
    )

    salary_payer_rel = relationship(
        "Maker",
        back_populates="publications_paid",
        foreign_keys=[salary_payer_id],
        primaryjoin="Publication.salary_payer_id == Maker.id",
    )


class Maker(Base):
    __tablename__ = "makers"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    discord_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BigInteger, unique=True)
    nickname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255), unique=True)
    level: Mapped[Literal["-1", "1", "2", "3", "4"]] = mapped_column(server_default="1")
    status: Mapped[Literal["new", "active", "inactive"]] = mapped_column(
        server_default="new"
    )
    warns: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(server_default="0")
    appointment_datetime = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    account_status: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(server_default="1")

    publications_made = relationship(
        "Publication",
        back_populates="maker_rel",
        foreign_keys=[Publication.maker_id],
        primaryjoin="Maker.id == Publication.maker_id",
    )

    publications_created = relationship(
        "Publication",
        back_populates="information_creator_rel",
        foreign_keys=[Publication.information_creator_id],
        primaryjoin="Maker.id == Publication.information_creator_id",
    )

    publications_paid = relationship(
        "Publication",
        back_populates="salary_payer_rel",
        foreign_keys=[Publication.salary_payer_id],
        primaryjoin="Maker.id == Publication.salary_payer_id",
    )


class MakerAction(Base):
    __tablename__ = "maker_actions"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    maker_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
    made_by: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
    action: Mapped[
        Literal[
            "addmaker",
            "deactivate",
            "setnickname",
            "setdiscord",
            "setlevel",
            "setstatus",
            "warn",
            "unwarn",
        ]
    ] = mapped_column()
    meta: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255), nullable=True)
    timestamp = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    reason: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255), nullable=True)


class PublicationAction(Base):
    __tablename__ = "publication_actions"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    publication_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
    made_by: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
    action: Mapped[
        Literal[
            "createpub",
            "deletepub",
            "setpub_id",
            "setpub_date",
            "setpub_maker",
            "setpub_status",
            "setpub_amount",
            "setpub_infocreator",
            "setpub_salarypayer",
        ]
    ] = mapped_column()
    meta: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255), nullable=True)
    timestamp = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    reason: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255), nullable=True)
```

So connection should be closed after executing a query and then new connection should be established.

And this is how I get data in my Flask app:

```py
@app.route("/")
async def some_handler():
    ...
        makers = methods.get_all_makers_sorted()
        active_makers = []
        for i in makers:
            if i.account_status:
                i.level = get_level_title(i.level)
                i.status = get_status_title(i.status)
                active_makers.append(i)
        return render_template(
            "index.html",
            is_logged=True,
            id=user_data["id"],
            avatar=user_data["avatar"],
            nickname=maker.nickname,
            makers=active_makers,
        )
```

I want it to connect properly at first query even after a few hours downtime. What can I do?

Comment: Worth reading: [Dealing With Disconnects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects) and [Connection Timeouts and Disconnects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mysql.html#connection-timeouts-and-disconnects).

Comment: With your current code you probably need to call `engine.dispose()` to clear out the connection pool before reconnecting.